Question about electric field around charge density
Suppose the region $0 < x < d$ has charge density $-p$, and the region $-d < x < 0$ has charge density $p$. Why is electric field on the edge of region in point d zero? If negatively charged region is closer to the point then positively charged region.

What's the topology of this region? Line, plane, loop? How did you come to this conclusion? You need to give more information.
